# SQL Server SA Password for SQL Server Authentication?

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-authentication, sql-server-authentication

I am working on SQL Server 2008 and currently I am using my local server with windows authentication. Can i set SA password for SQL Server Authentication? What are the steps and also I want to know what is the difference between Windows and SQL Server Authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Window Authentication:** If you are authorized user to window and you have proper right to access sql server. you are all done to access sql server, you don't need any username/password to access sql server.

**SQL Server Authentication:** You need to create new user to access sql server (a part from window user). You need username & password of newly created user to access sql server.

You can create new SQL Server Authentication user by: Object Explorer >> Security >> Login >> New Login. Again, you need required right for the window user through which currently you are accessing sql server.